# Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net, ngreact

Built JSX with JsxBundleConfig, used angular ngReact directives to render react within angular. Every time i tried to include a react-component, the error Cannot read property 'render' of undefined appeared in the console, and nothing was rendered

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After knocking my head against the wall for a while, i found out that the react-dom js was not included in my project.

Comment: Thank god, you saved my wall :)

Comment: In my case it stopped working after upgrading reactjs, so i guess they were splitting functionality into separate files at some point. Not including the new "react-dom.js" file causes this particular error.

Comment: They split that on the version after 13.3.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include following lines

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

hope I have help someone.